# How do I get a list of all taxonomy terms assigned to a node?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a node and want to get all the taxonomy terms assigned to the node.

In drupal 6 I could use `$node->taxonomy` and the `taxonomy_*` functions but these don't exist in drupal 7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Taxonomy terms are implemented in fields in Drupal 7. Assuming you have defined a taxonomy field named field_category for your content type, you can access it as:

```
$language = 'und'; // or will be provided by some Drupal hooks
foreach ($node->field_category[$language] as $delta => $value) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($value['tid']);
}
```

If you don't have access to the field name, probably the easiest way *for nodes* is to query the database directly:

```
$results = db_query('SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_index} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid' => $node->nid));
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($result->tid);
}
```

Keep in mind though, that you may end up dealing a jumble of terms from different vocabularies if you have more than one taxonomy field.

Comment: What if I don't know the taxonomy field name? The names will differ between content types and I want to get all of the terms for any node.

Comment: Added a method if you don't know the field name.

Comment: Especially in the second version, you can use `taxonomy_term_load_multiple($results->fetchCol());` to load the terms in a single query.

Comment: Oh, and you can use `field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_category')` to get the fields in the correct language.

Comment: Note the select from taxonomy_index technique works only with published nodes.  That table is not maintained for unpublished content.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very generic way to grab all terms without specifying field names and no db_query:

```
function example_get_terms($node) {
  $terms = array();

  foreach (field_info_instances('node', $node->type) as $fieldname => $info) {
    foreach (field_get_items('node', $node, $fieldname) as $item) {
      if (is_array($item) && !empty($item['tid']) && $term = taxonomy_term_load($item['tid'])) {
        $terms[] = $term->name;
      }
    }
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

Comment: For Drupal beginner, i would add `if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {$nid = arg(1);}` to get the `nid` and `$node = node_load($nid);` in order to make your function work.