# Add next/prev link to image in drupal 7

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, paging

I have a taxonomy with lots of nodes in it. Each node contains a large image. I want that image to be linked to the next node within the taxnomy. How can I do this in Drupal 7?

Comment: Are you displaying details using views or you want above functionality in node landing page ?

Comment: I want it on the node's landing page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested to use a more flexible module, [Custom pagers](http://drupal.org/project/custom_pagers) will do the job. Overlay the "next" link above the image using CSS absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the solution that should work !

- Hook into node view using [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) by writing a custom module.
- Change the image field to a image with link using below technique

  1. Get nid of current node using $node->nid;
  2. Get taxonomy term id associated with node object using this [technique](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8722/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-taxonomy-terms-assigned-to-a-node).
  3. Get all other nodes attached with same taxonomy term that you got in step 2 using [taxonomy_select_nodes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7)
  4. From the list of node id's that you got in step 3 check the node id which is just greater than $node->nid and store it in variable $next_nid
  5. Form a link using l function that should be markup for image field.

  $overrided_image_field_value = l($image, 'node/' . $next_nid, array('html' => TRUE));

That should do the work !

Answer (score -1):

I would use the [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module to have a view block with all the nodes belonging to the taxonomy term that is being viewed at the time.
Aspects such as adding next/previous links are 'easy' using views slideshow. For node that contain large images this module should be more than apt for the job.The link should get you started.

Comment: I don't really want to apply a slideshow effect to my images cause I'm trying to make a comic site