# Getting taxonomy terms selected in node as objects not index

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom module in place to get details of a node after the node has been submitted. I am trying to collect all the taxonomy terms associated with that node. The taxonomy terms are selected by multiple check boxes on the node creation page.

$items = $form['field_content_type_list']['und']['#value'];

and then go through them in a for loop:

foreach ($items as $item)

The problem is that $item is the index in the taxonomy list rather than the name of the object itself as a string.

Is there a way of getting the string value rather than the index of the term?

Thanks

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8722/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-taxonomy-terms-assigned-to-a-node/8723?noredirect=1#comment112647_8723

Comment: When I want to echo($term) it's null... How do I echo the value?

Comment: Are you sure this field is a taxonomy reference, not a list?  The name "field_content_type_list" is suspicious.  In your follow-up comment, you do not say how `$term` is defined, so I am just guessing that you have defined it.  If so, then install the Devel module and use `dsm($term);` instead of `echo.