# How do I get a list of all taxonomy terms assigned to a node (or any entity)?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

What's the best way to get all taxonomy terms assigned to a node?

Should one use the taxonomy_index table?

Should one iterate through the fields on the node object?

I saw some answers for [Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8722/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-taxonomy-terms-assigned-to-a-node), but not for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to iterate through each field and check if it's an entity_reference field with target type taxonomy_term, then extract the data you need.

```
$terms = [];

foreach ($node->getFields() as $key => $field) {
  if ($field->getFieldDefinition()->getType() == 'entity_reference') {
    $targetType = $field->getFieldDefinition()
      ->getItemDefinition()
      ->getSetting('target_type');
    if ($targetType == 'taxonomy_term') {
      $new_terms = array_map(function (\Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface $term) {
        return $term->label();
      }, $field->referencedEntities());
      $terms = array_merge($terms, $new_terms);
    }
  }
}
```

One advantage to this approach is it will work with any fieldable entity type.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with the taxonomy_index table:

```
$terms = [];

$query = \Drupal::database()
  ->select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
  ->fields('ti', ['tid'])
  ->condition('nid', $node->id());

$results = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

$tids = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadMultiple($results);

$terms = [];

foreach ($tids as $term) {
  $terms[] = $term->label();
}
```

Note: this will only work with node entities.